# How to set a storyboard id to a ViewController without using interface builder?

Tags: swift, storyboard

I've been searching answers to this but all tutorial with "programatically setting up the storyboardid" ends up using an actual Storyboard to set the viewcontroller's storyboard id and only does the "programatically" part when navigating. Is there ever a way to assign the storyboard id to a viewcontroller programatically like do it in appdelegate or viewdidload?

Comment: Can you tell a little bit more about you use case?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Hust, why do you want to set it?

Comment: So I can use storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWIthIdentifier without getting a nil result. That's why I wish to set the identifier programatically.

Comment: Why don't you assign an identifier with interface builder?

Comment: Cuz I don't use interface builder. I do everything programatically.

Comment: You cannot create or fill storyboards programmatically. When you use no interface builder, your storyboard will be empty (or not existent).

Comment: I see, so theres just no way of doing that. Well if you could put your comment to the answer area, I'll give it a thumbs up. Also edited the title as to the correct keyword I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create or fill storyboards programmatically. When you use no interface builder, your storyboard will be empty (or not existent).